# VMware Studio Plugin for Eclipse Installing Error

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, vmware, vmware-player

I tried to install VMware studio plugin for eclipse 3.5.2 and i got this error.

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: VMware Studio Plugin for Eclipse 2.5.0.0-387333 (com.vmware.studio.eclipse.feature.group 2.5.0.0-387333)
  Missing requirement: VMware Studio Plugin for Eclipse 2.5.0.0-387333 (com.vmware.studio.eclipse.feature.group 2.5.0.0-387333) requires 'org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group 0.0.0' but it could not be found

i tried with this [document](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/studio/studio21/eclipse_plugin.html)

please advise me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are starting with a version of Eclipse that has the web tooling stuff in it, like [this one](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-javascript-web-developers/indigosr1).

Go to `Help -> About Eclipse` and push the "Installation Details" button and look at the features tab and see if you have the org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui Feature installed. If not, then try to look for it in `Help -> Install New Software` using the update site that goes with your version of Eclipse.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.i checked the Eclipse and it shows org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui Feature as installed.

Comment: That's very odd, I would file a bug with the Eclipse p2 project then, it sounds like something is messed up.